# What would be the driving political force behind pushes to ban no fault evictions?

Tags: united-kingdom, legislation, housing

Landlords are professionally organized into trade bodies like the NRLA, and quite well at that.

Tenants are more rag tag and grassroots although tenant rights groups like shelter are also reasonably well funded, and a parallel question would really be how they are.

Anyway banning no fault evictions is a huge step for tenants but where does the drive to do so arise? What incentive do politicians have to put through such an initiative? Where does the motivation come from? Are tenants' advocacy groups really that strong? Do politicians really care what they think?

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-61817249

Comment: *What incentive do politicians have to put through such an initiative?* Have you thought about votes?

Comment: More tenants than landlords, eviction stories are always a hit in papers, landlords aren't generally seen as sympathetic characters, trade bodies dont generally have as much leverage as say a union.  And well maybe the balance is too far on the landlord side right now (keeping in mind that too much tenant rights may also dissuade rentals...) + Votes, votes, votes as SJuan76 said.  I mean it's all matter of opinion but...

Comment: The tag should probably be E&W, as section 21 evictions no longer exist in Scotland.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I wrote my answer before I saw your comment. Any similarity is coincidental - honest. :-)

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff great minds think alike ;-)

Comment: Could it be the simple reason that it is the right thing to do?

Comment: It seems like a very pessimistic view of politics to think that any politician who ever does anything only does so because of some lobbying group. Many politicians may occasionally act for that reason, and some do much more often and to a greater degree than others, but politicians in a democracy ultimately exist to enact the will of the people, and laws are there to prevent people from doing "wrong" things.

Comment: @AvinKavish Many things in life are not that clear cut. From a tenant point of view, then yes, this seems a like a no-brainer. From a landlord point of view, it's more complicated.

Comment: @NotThatGuy  Pessimism may be justified in this case.  Boris Johnson is very unpopular with both the electorate and his own party.  He has two by-elections this week and the polls are looking bad for him.  He's also been introducing unrelated, populist policies on the fly, such as moving away from metric measurements, deportation of asylum seekers to Rwanda, civil service cuts, privatising Channel 4 etc. etc.

Comment: One must reckon with how things came to be in their current state wherein no fault evictions are allowed if one wishes to suggest that the answer as to how they are coming to be banned is so obvious.

Comment: @JosephP. That's an interesting point. You should ask a question about the origins of section 21!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are more tenants than there are landlords, plus landlords aren't generally a popular crowd. Hence appealing to tenant voters is likely to garner more votes than appealing to landlord voters.

In addition, stories in the media about the seeming arbitrariness of "no-fault" (section 21) evictions may help make the move more popular (and hence generate more votes) among voters who aren't tenants but may have been in the past, or who empathise with evictees.

Comment: I assume that the BBC articles are part of a coordinated political push of some sort to raise  support for the initiative, rather than candidly preceding it. They seem clearly designed to spread political support for banning no fault evictions.

Comment: I don't know about co-ordinated; but the Government have been clear in their message, and so the media are publicising it. There's nothing unusual about this. What's distinctive about landlord-tenant issues is that parties have to be wary about appearing to be pro-landlord; so opposition may focus on the government not going far enough on tenants' rights, for example.

Comment: Also, stability in housing increases city revenues indirectly, because it allows local businesses to exist in a stable environment, while a volatile environment can only be navigated by large chains that are usually minimizing their local tax and wage spending quite effectively.